# Call a C program in Java

Tags: java, c, call

I know there is already some posts about this but none of them answered my question.

Here's the situation, I have program written in C but I developped my GUI in java. So what I need to do, is calling my C program when I click on a button or a combobox.

In order to do that, is it possible to just compile the C program and then call it in my java interface ? (and if it is possible, how do I do that ?).

Or do I **have to** use JNI ? (I've read some posts about it but it seemed quite complicated to learn it for just one project).

Comment: Yes you have to use JNI to call native methods from Java

Comment: If you need the C code to interoperate with the Java program then using JNI (or JNA) is the correct solution. If you just want to start a compiled program then you might execute it via system commands (note that this can cause a lot of other problems)

Comment: This won't end well.  You ought to think about this more carefully.  Port that C program to Java.  It's time.  You'll spare yourself a lot of heartache.  The "savings" you'll accrue by reusing that C executable aren't worth the pain.

Comment: Thanks but I will use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() as mention below I think. This is for a project at school and we completed C files given by the profesor, I know using JNI would be better but I don't have time to do that. Furthermore, I don't even know every function used in the C file so I don't think I'll be able to port that in Java.

Comment: Fair enough.  Sounds like your professor is stuck in 1990.  Too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have maximum interoperability you should use JNI, but as a simple approach just compile C code and call C executable from JAVA with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

if you are under UNIX to read response you could do something like this:

```
String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "/path/to/C/executable" );

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
in.close();
```

Comment: Runtime.exec was obsoleted a long time ago by [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: @VGR yes sorry...it has been a while since I last used Java... If you want you can edit my answer